# Node/Express.js - Get XML with HTTP-Post and convert it to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js, express

My task is seemingly simple: A server posts a XML-File. I take that XML-File and convert it to JSON and return this via res.send();
Im using Node.js with Express, the express-bodyparser, the xml2js library and express-json. (also tried express-xml-bodyparser)

My Code for this should look something like this:

```
    [...]
    app.post('/postXML', function(req,res,next){
      xml2jsParser.parseString(req.body, function(err, result){
        if(!err){
          res.send(result);
        }else{
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
      parser.reset();
    });
    [...]
```

My Problem is: req.body looks something like this `{" /*XML-file*/ "}`
typeof returns [object]. The xml2js parser cant work with that. So my two solutions looked something like this:

1. JSON.stringify() that thing and remove the first two and the last
   two chars and you are good to go.  But apparently JSON.stringify()
   interpretes the object as a String escaping every quotation mark
   with a backslash, thus making it unusable for my xmlparser.
2. .toString the body or String(req.body), again cutting of the extra chars. I found out, that you cant do that either. It is again escaping the quotationmarks. (using bodyParser.text() doesnt seem to work either)

The xml2js needs a string looking something like this:

```
var xml = "<outer><inner attributename = "content"></inner></outer>"
```

The XML file that gets posted has the right form and is per default well-formed. I have tested it manually with xml2json and it works fine. The content that I get is also right just not in the right form. For further automating i just need to get this working via Http-post.

Comment: How exactly does `req.body` look like?

Comment: Something like this: {"<?xml version":"\"1.0\"?><outer><inner attributename = \"content\"></inner></outer>"} if i put it in console.log().

Comment: Any luck with this?